# Chai check that an array includes an object that includes keys

Tags: mocha.js, chai

I am having an issue while doing integration tests with Chai. I want to check that an array includes an object which contains some keys. In this case, I am adding an address to a user and I wish to check that when the user is returned, the addresses array contains the fields that I originally passed, but without checking the `ObjectId` generated by MongoDB. I have been using [chai things](https://github.com/chaijs/chai-things) for array operations.

I have a working solution when I know that the element I am checking is at index 0 in the form of the assertion below:

```
expect(response.body.addresses[0]).to.deep.include({
                text: '123, fake street',
                loc: {
                    type: 'Point',
                    coordinates: [0, 0]
                }
});
```

What I want is to utilise `chai-things` to assert that the array contains an object which meets the same requirement as the above assertion. The closest solution i could come up with is:

```
expect(response.body.addresses).to.contain.something.that.deep.includes({
                  text: '123, fake street',
                  loc: {
                      type: 'Point',
                      coordinates: [0, 0]
                  }
});
```

But this fails with: `AssertionError: expected { Object (text, _id, ...) } to deep include { text: '123, fake street',
  loc: { type: 'Point', coordinates: [ 0, 0 ] } }`

Is there a way to achieve this without being dependent on the location of the object in the array?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried using chai-things for this as well and couldn't get it right. Ended up using [chai-subset](https://www.npmjs.com/package/chai-subset)

in your test setup:

`chai.use(require('chai-subset'))`

and in the test

```
expect(response.body.addresses).to.containSubset([{
  text: '123, fake street',
  loc: {
    type: 'Point',
    coordinates: [0, 0]
  }
}])
```